# Working out which out of two numbers are closer to another number Java

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to figure out a way to work out which out of two numbers are closer to another number lets say we have int a,b,c

a = 0.7 b = 1.8 and c = 1;

How in Java would I work out which number out of a or b is closer to c.

Comment: How are you being presented your data? Is it always 3 numbers? Is it an array? The solution will be very different depending on whether your number of inputs is fixed or not.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by use this Function by   coll `MyF( a , b , c )`

```
String MyF(double a , double b , double c )
    {
     if (Math.abs(c - a) < Math.abs(c - b)) 
         return a;
     else
        return b;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
double a = 0.7;
double b = 1.8;
double c = 1;

// Compare the absolute values of the differences
double closer = Math.abs(c - a) < Math.abs(c - b) ? a : b;
System.out.println(closer);

// 0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the minimum of the absolute value of the difference (0.3 and 0.8 in your case).

```
if (Math.abs(a-c) <= Math.abs(b-c)) {
  System.out.println("A is closer");
} else {
  System.out.println("B is closer");
}
```

Note that 0.3 and 1.8 have to be `float`/`double`, and not `int` as your question states.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a more generic solution for your interest, if you want a 
`Comparator` that can compare the closeness of numbers to another number then it would look like this:

```
Comparator<Double> closenessToC = Comparator.comparingDouble(n -> Math.abs(c - n));
```

This could work for any set of numbers (rather than just two):

```
Stream.of(4.5, 8.9, -11.2).min(closenessToC).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you being presented your data? Is it always 3 numbers? Is it an array? The solution will be very different depending on whether your number of inputs is fixed or not.

Wrote up the following to find you the closest 2 numbers in an array of numbers.

```
public class Test {

    static double[] findClosest(double[] dblArray) {
        double[] closest = new double[2];

        //int diff will keep track of the best of the differences
        //between the numbers we are compairing. Need to start off at 
        //largest number possible.
        double bestDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        //currDiff will calculate the current difference in doubles
        double currDiff;

        //You want to iterate through every value you have
        for (int i = 0; i < dblArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dblArray.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) { //You don't want it to compare to itself.
                    //System.out.println("Subtracting: " + dblArray[i] + " - " + dblArray[j]);
                    currDiff = Math.abs(dblArray[i] - dblArray[j]);
                    if (currDiff < bestDiff) {
                        closest[0] = dblArray[i];
                        closest[1] = dblArray[j];
                        bestDiff = currDiff;
                       // System.out.println("Setting closest:" + dblArray[i] + ", " + dblArray[j] + ", bestDiff: " + bestDiff);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return closest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] testArray = new double[]{.7, 1.8, 1};
        double[] resultArray = findClosest(testArray);
        System.out.println("Closest were: " + resultArray[0] + ", " + resultArray[1]);
    }
}
```

Running this you get:

```
run:
Closest were: 0.7, 1.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I know it's not the most practical to return an array just for 2 values, I could've returned a String, but the point was to demonstrate the logic. I also realised you were asking for `a` and `b` to be compared to `c`. You can use the logic in the code I wrote above and tweak it a little to accomplish that.